# Cannot install yo on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I have installed the latest version of node and rebooted the system. I am not behind a proxy.

After running

```
npm install -g yo
```

Following error occurs

```
C:\>npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\index.js
C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> yo@2.0.5 postinstall C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
> yodoctor


**Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system**

C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\global-tunnel-ng\index.js:231
    throw e;
    ^

**Error: upstream proxy port is required**
    at Object.globalTunnel.initialize (C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\global-tunnel-ng\index.js:192:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-doctor\lib\cli.js:6:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
**npm ERR! yo@2.0.5 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@2.0.5 postinstall script.**
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-14T14_55_52_156Z-debug.log
```

and when I run `yo --version`

It shows

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\US\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Also please format so that it is easier to read the question

Comment: No, I am not behind a proxy server.

Comment: I didn't install and use yo and left it. I found an alternative solution to create project.

Answer (score 1):

Run the cmd with "Run as administrator" privilege. In my case it was a file access issue.